# HTML5: Why wont my local database work on mobile Safari?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, html, web-applications, cordova

**Testing in safari/chrome/mobi-tester**:

`works fine`

**Testing on a friend's iphone 4 running iOS 4.3.3**:

`works fine`

**Testing on my iPod touch running iOS 4.0.2**:

```
Javascript Error on Line 26...INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11:...
```

..and does not load the list of music events

---

The function causing the error is (on mobile safari only) is:

```
window.openDatabase();
```

I thought this should be no problem for iOS 4.0.2?

Comment: If someone else could test the link from their `iphone3` or `< ios 4.3` and confirm that the list of music events does not load, that would be really appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly I would say this problem from the current firmware you are using,

because I have tested with iPod touch iOS 4.3.3 and iPhone 3G and they are ok with no error.

You may want to hear some more from other people opinion but mine was no problem.

Comment: Hi Ali, I'm pretty sure it's my personal ipod. Perhaps when i deleted the database (in `settings->safari->offline databases) it blocked my site for my ipod?

Comment: possibly I would say that come from a specific version of the firmware iOS 4.3.x has a huge change and improvement from iOS 4.0.x then I would rather check again with my iPhone 4 and it works fine here even I tested with iPod touch 4G running on iOS 4.2 both working here

Comment: Cool man, really appreciated. Sounds like you've got a whole load of phones!

Comment: @Haroldo hehe yeah I'm currently creating a webapp and also I'm an Apple fan so really need them for testing :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm late to this. FWIW, it sounds like the database on your iPod touch is out of date. Have you tried deleting it and having the code re-create it? You can delete databases via the relevant section in Safari options on your iOS device.